# I need to list the files between two revisions along with revision number in svn

Tags: shell, svn

I need to summarize the list of files between two revisions along with revision number.

So far i have tried,

I m able to get the list of files between two revisions. but not revision number.
Can you suggest me to get the revision number

My Try:

```
svn diff -r $revisionNumber:HEAD --summarize <URL> > Filelist.csv
```

this code outputs,

```
A      <URL>/file1.java 
M      <URL>/file2.java 
M      <URL>/file3.java
```

I would like to get the same list but with the revision number to be append for each of the file.

may be it will looks like,

> A      /file1.java 105
>
> M      /file2.java 103
>
> M      /file3.java 102

isn't clear???? ...

I have searched this question here. i could not able find it. if its a duplicate question kindly redirect me to the question that already posted..

Comment: I don't think subversion can do this. You'll either have to ask for last modified revision of each of those files (probably easier) or use `log --diff` and collect the output (possibly with `--xml` for easier parsing). In either case, what do you need it for? Maybe there is another approach?

Comment: @JanHudec - not log, but `ls -v URL/OF/FILE`

Comment: @LazyBadger: You want list of files with revisions in which they changed. There are two ways to get that information. Get a list of files and ask for revision of each or get a list of revisions and ask for files changed in each. Either way you'll need a bit of script.

Comment: @JanHudec yes, scripting anyway, but - `svn ls -v` is just easier parseable from my POV

Comment: @LazyBadger: Probably yes. I never claimed otherwise. Except if you wanted all revisions the file changed in rather than the last one.

Comment: @JanHudec - **I** want *notning* - I just translated OP's request this way: get list of files, affected by revision-range and and last-modified revision of each file in this range